# Prevent M2E From Creating Project Specific Settings

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

We recently decided that we want to share our Eclipse warnings settings so that all developers use the same ones (also save actions and formatter configuration). This of course means we want to remove all project specific settings. We created all the necessary plug-ins from scratch and are now able to display problems with quickfixes whenever project specific settings are still present.

So we now came to know that M2E selects the checkbox *"Enable project specific settings"* for the preference page *"Java Compiler -> Errors / Warnings"* on any Maven update (which usually happens quite often).

(Or adds the key value pair `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning` to *.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs*.)

I think it's clear that it's absolutely unacceptable for a build tool to create project specific settings of any kind, much less to tinker with the forbidden references.

So how do I prevent M2E from doing just that?